# Unmap "delete file" in Explore mode

Tags: key-bindings

I just accidentally deleted an important file in `:Ex` (I thought I was still typing a search string and hit `Shift+D` and then `Enter` immediately).

Can I unmap this entirely to avoid this (stupid and not very likely, but still annoying) risk in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to unmap `D` only for the filetype `netrw` to do that you can create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` and inside put the following lines:

```
" Avoid unwanted file deletions with D
unmap <buffer> D
```

Then you should be good to go, `D` will not do the suppression anymore.

How does it work?

See [`:h ftplugin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin), the idea is to create a file which will be sourced when the filetype of a buffer is set to `netrw` but *after* the Netrw plugin did it's own configurations so that you can override them. Note that instead you can probably use an autocommand, but I think it would be pretty redundant since that would be not using the built-in Vim mechanisms.

And the `<buffer>` parameter to the `unmap` command is necessary because Netrw remaps `D` only in its own buffers.